# Object not created in ion slide box

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ion slide box and one of my slides contains a progress bar (from [here](https://gist.github.com/jsoncylu/2a7406cefc1f3192200892ab6cb03a19)). The way I initialize the progress bar is in the slide controller:

```
//partial code

var appControl = angular.module('volCtrlPanel.controllers', []);

appControl.controller('VolIndCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http, $rootScope) {
    var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#progress', {
    color: '#FCB03C',
    trailColor: '#ddd',
    strokeWidth: 3,
    duration: 55
  });

  var defaultVol = 0;

  circle.set(defaultVol);
```

And my div that contains the progress bar is in a template in my index.html:

```
<script id="templates/control.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <ion-view>
            <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
                <ion-slide>
                <div class="center" id="background">
                  <div id="button-container">
                    <!-- this is the container for progress bar -->
                    <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>

                  </div>
                </div>
                </ion-slide>
            </ion-slide-box>
        </ion-view>
    </script>
```

However, I get an error saying that the progress bar container does not exist.

```
 ionic.bundle.js:20434 Error: Container does not exist: #progress
```

I don't get this error if I remove the slide box tags but I need it to be a slide. The container clearly exists in the div, so I'm not sure why the ion slide box is changing things all of a sudden. It leads me to think that the progress bar object is not being created when in a slide? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please post all your code to be able to run the app and reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by creating the Circle in Ionic's $ionicView.beforeEnter state.

The "container does not exist" happens because it's trying to find a container that does not exist yet. Hence, I put the initialization of the Circle before the view is loaded.